# MDE.Windows Azure VM extension provisioning failed

Tags: azure, azure-security, windows-defender, azure-security-center

We have recently migrated Windows server 2016 from Onprem to Azure Cloud. After that i notice that the "MDE.Windows" extension shows "Provisioning Failed" message. And below is the error message. Can someone help me on how to fix this?

```
[2022-10-18 13:19:05Z][Error] Failed to configure Microsoft Defender for Endpoint: Onboarding to MDE via Microsoft Defender for Cloud for this operating system is done using Microsoft Monitor Agent. If you would like to install the new MDE Unified Solution/Agent, please enable the Unified Solution setting in Microsoft Defender for Cloud (vNextEnabled parameter is not 'true')\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have enabled the defender cloud*

*When enabling the defender for servers plan 1 or plan 2 and configuring the defender for end point integration
The end point defender is automatically provisioned for all supported machines*

[image]

*If we want we can change the sever plan also
we have to enable the defender for endpoint integration
by clicking on* ***settings => integrations***

*I have enabled the auto provisioning when using defender for cloud*
[image]

*I have selected the appropriate Virtual Machine*

[image]

*We have to monitor the installation via azure machine extension page*
*Open the specific VM => Open the extension&Application => open the MDE.windows for related information*

[image]

*While clicking on the MDE.Windows extensions we can see the state is succeeded*

[image]

***NOTE:***
*When the extension is failed we have to check the all below the pre requisites are correctly configured or not*

*1). Defender not running inactive mode for 2019*

*2). Defender server role is not installed for server 2016*

*3). connect pre requisites updates not installed*

*4). Defender disabled via registry key setting*

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the error message, Unified Agent MDE auto-provisioning setting must be turned on in order for the Unified Agent to be installed. Otherwise, the MDE.Windows extension will fail with that message , and MDE will only be onboarded using Log Analytics agent.
The setting can be turned on using Auto Provisioning under Settings.